# How did they find the nontrivial solution? Did my book miss a step?

Tags: linear-algebra

I feel like my textbook skipped a step here. How did they find the solution to this? Can someone show me the Gaussian elimination step? How did they get the nontrivial solution?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $v_1 = 3v_2 +v_3$,

we have $$v_1-3v_2-v_3 = 0$$

Hence $(1,-3, -1)$ is a solution for $(c_1, c_2, c_3) $ in

$$c_1v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3=0$$

Comment: Ummmm how did you find that? Gaussian elimination? Show steps?

Comment: you mean find which? are you referring to the first line? in that case, refer to example $1a$, they claim they show it there.